# VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to clip  a dataset but i get the following error:

**Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Desktop\py_magn\SnippingMap.py", line 66
res = np.array((x, y, clipMag)).T
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray**

the dataset are magnetic measurements and dimensions x,y in km of the area. with this code i try to crop the area in 90x90.
the code is:

```
root= tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()
def getCSV ():
    global df
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = np.genfromtxt(import_file_path, delimiter='_', missing_values = ' ', filling_values = None)
    
    print (df)
    
browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text=" Import CSV File to clip ", command=getCSV, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=browseButton_CSV)
root.mainloop()
x, y, mag = df[:,0], df[:,1], df[:,3]
xmin, ymin = np.min(x), np.min(y)
xc, yc = (xmin + (90/2)), (ymin + (90/2)) # 90 einai to mege8os toy para8yrou
print(xmin,xc)
def clipping( x, y, mag, xc, yc):
    
    xmini, ymini = xc - 45, yc - 45
    xmaxi, ymaxi = xc + 45, xc + 45
    print(xmaxi, xc)
    count=0
    for i in x:
         if i>=xmini and i<=xmaxi:
             count += 1
    clipMag = mag[:count]
    xn, yn = np.unique(x), np.unique(y)
    
    ind = np.where(xn == xmini)
    ind=ind[0][0]
    xn = np.linspace(xmini, xmaxi, int(mt.sqrt(len(clipMag))))
    yn = np.linspace(ymini, ymaxi, int(mt.sqrt(len(clipMag))))
    print(xn, np.shape(xn))
    xn, yn = np.meshgrid(xn, yn)
    x, y = np.reshape(xn, (1,np.shape(xn)[0]*np.shape(xn)[1])), np.reshape(yn, (1,np.shape(yn)[0]*np.shape(yn)[1]))
    
    
    
    res = np.array((x, y, clipMag)).T
    root= tk.Tk()
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
    canvas1.pack()
    def saveCSV ():
        global df
    
        export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename( defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[("CSV files", '*.csv')])
        np.savetxt(export_file_path, res, delimiter='_')
    
    
    browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text="      Export filled CSV Data File     ", command=saveCSV, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_CSV)
    root.mainloop()

while True:
    
    if (xc+45)>=np.max(x):
        if (yc+45)>=np.max(y):
            clipping(x, y, mag, xc, yc)
            break
        else:
            xc = xmin + (90/2)
            yc = yc + 45
    else:
        clipping(x, y, mag, xc, yc)
        xc = xc + 45
```

The data are in .csv

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. You can do as written in the warning message (`dtype=object`) to prevent it.

Comment: It's warning that these 3 arrays `(x, y, clipMag)` differ in shape, and the resulting array will be object dtype and 1d.  The fact that you follow that with a `.T` suggests that you expect the result to be 2d (or higher).  The use of that array in `savetxt` also  means it should be 2d numeric.  You need to review the shape of those 3 array inputs.  Something is wrong there.

Comment: @hpaulj i miscalculate the shape and now the shape are ok but i continue to have the same warning and also i cant export them to a csv

Comment: @Stef setting the dtype=object, i get the following error when i try to export :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\py_magn\SnippingMap.py", line 77, in saveCSV
    np.savetxt(export_file_path, res, delimiter='_')
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in savetxt
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1426, in savetxt
    raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Comment: Examine the array that you are trying to save.  I told you the savetxf required a 2d numeric dtype array.

Comment: the data are float and i want them to be saved as 4 rows in a csv. but i dont know in what dtype i need to save it

Comment: @hpaulj with dtype=object i get the traceback i commented before

Comment: I still think you have the wrong shapes in the source 3 arrays.  Adding the `dtype=object` just turns off the warning; it doesn't make the correct array.  You want a `dtype=float` array.

Comment: @hpaulj with dtype=float i get the following error:

Comment: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\py_magn\SnippingMap.py", line 99, in <module>
    clipping(x, y, mag, xc, yc)
  File "C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\py_magn\SnippingMap.py", line 67, in clipping
    res = np.array((xn, yn, df[:,2], clipMag), dtype=float).T
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: That's further confirmation that your 3 arrays are not compatible is shape.  That's what the initial warning was all about.

Comment: but i printed the shape and it is the same

Answer (score 0):

So i changed the code and specifically the clipping() function. I use pandas
:

```
def clipping( x, y, z, mag, xc, yc):
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y, 'Z':z, 'MAG':mag})
    df1['geometry'] = list(zip(df1['X'], df1['Y'], df1['Z']))
    df1['geometry'] = df1['geometry'].apply(Point)
    gdfMAGN = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry='geometry')
    
    x1, y1 = xc, yc
    # ____________[90000m X 90000m] IS THE WINDOW DIMENSIONS______________
    
    clipAr = Polygon([ (x1, y1), (x1, y1+90000), (x1 + 90000, y1 + 90000), (x1+90000, y1)])
    pol = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[clipAr] )
    
    res = gpd.clip(gdfMAGN, pol)
    resCSV = np.array([res['X'],res['Y'],res['Z'],res['MAG']]).T
    
    
    #---------------------START---SAVE---------------------
    root= tk.Tk()

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'gray1', relief = 'raised')
    canvas1.pack()

    def saveCSV ():
        global df
    
        export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename( defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[("CSV files", '*.csv')])
        np.savetxt(export_file_path, resCSV, delimiter='_')
    
    
    browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text="      Export filled CSV Data File     ", command=saveCSV, bg='OrangeRed4', fg='black', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_CSV)

    root.mainloop()
    #------------------------END---SAVE--------------------
```